# How can data preloading be implemented with NserviceBus?

Tags: nservicebus

I use NserviceBus to implement some plugins to my main application. Main application is a web site. During startup plugin needs to retrieve some data from main application(i.e. all users), and then to handle any changes to this data. In order always to have up to date data.

The problem I see is that we preload data asynchronously, so while that preloading I can't handle any changes from main application, because plugin is still not set up.

How this scenario can be implemented with NserviceBus? I mean how can I delay message handling until preload is completed. It seems this is common scenraion so the solution should be simple, but I fail to find an easy one.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't store the data you need in your website and just use NSB to keep that "Read Only Model" in sync? (possibly using ETL to do the first one time load of the data)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I don't want to use other transport protocols except NSB for communication between my plugins and main application. The idea I have is to have special flag like PreloadingIsInProgress. And call HandleCurrentMessageLater() in all handlers if this flag is true. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you use a Saga in NSB to keep track of all your pre-loading, and then ensure all your handlers verify there is no Saga in progress before they attempt to handle application change messages?

Comment: You could even specify this as another handler and require it runs first in the pipeline.

Comment: Andrew, this is the idea I also found as the best one. I'm not only sure how this plays with common SOA pattern, which tells not to have commands for retrieving data. Because this makes our services heavy connected. Or maybe it is ok in context of preloading?

Comment: Well in your scenario it seems more about delaying message handling until preloading has occurred rather than using commands for retrieving data, correct?

Comment: Correct. This is the main problem. So according to your answer : I skip all handlers, until preloading Saga is completed? But what if some data was added to main application when preloading is in progress? I'll get some mistiming between main application and plugin. Maybe I need to call HandleCurrentMessageLater() on all messages, until preloading is completed. But I'm afraid this can load CPU a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your bus manually and start it only after your data has been loaded:

```
bus = Configure.With()
    .StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container)
    .XmlSerializer()
    .MsmqTransport()
        .IsTransactional(true)
        .PurgeOnStartup(false)
    .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
    .Sagas()
    .UnicastBus()
        .ImpersonateSender(false)
    .CreateBus()
    .Start();
```

this is just an example. you have to edit the configuration for yourself.

for alternatives please post more details about the nature of your data and what transformations are being done with them.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Actually this approach is not ok to me. I'll describe my situation a bit deeper. Each plugin can have several Plugin Profiles(they are added from UI on main application). In my plugin I handle ProfileAddedMessage and need to do some profile specific data preloading (i.e. get all users from main application, without any transformations). But bus is already started at the moment and I can't stop it. But I want to skip all messages for this profile until preloading completed.